# Diesel print-schema doesn't generate joinable! for foreign keys (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship that I would like to do joins on. One table stores users, and the other stores cameras. The many-to-many table is used to store what cameras a user has access to. Multiple users can have access to a camera, hence the need for the many-to-many table. Here's the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cameras (
    camera_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name text NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password text NOT NULL
);
```

And this is the many-to-many table linking these two:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_cameras (
    users_cameras_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    camera_id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_camera_id
        FOREIGN KEY (camera_id)
            REFERENCES cameras (camera_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_user_id
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES users (user_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

When I run `diesel print-schema`, this is the output:

```rust
table! {
    cameras (camera_id) {
        camera_id -> Uuid,
        name -> Text,
    }
}

table! {
    users (user_id) {
        user_id -> Uuid,
        username -> Text,
        password -> Text,
    }
}

table! {
    users_cameras (users_cameras_id) {
        users_cameras_id -> Int4,
        camera_id -> Uuid,
        user_id -> Uuid,
    }
}

allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    cameras,
    users,
    users_cameras,
);
```

This doesn't generate the `joinable!` stuff, meaning that I can't perform joins for these tables. Am I laying out my data wrong, or is this a limitation of diesel?

Comment: I had a similar (but unrelated) issue, where I misspelled the table name in the `REFERENCES` clause.

Comment: @UnicornsOnLSD were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @Rusty I'm pretty sure I managed to fix it, although its been years since I've worked on this project (and used Diesel). The schemas in my final version look the same as in this question, so they probably weren't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is: you just need to separate those table creations into two migration.

**First migration:**

```
CREATE TABLE cameras (
camera_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
name text NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE users (
user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password text NOT NULL);
```

**Second migration:**

```
CREATE TABLE users_cameras (
users_cameras_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
camera_id uuid NOT NULL,
user_id uuid NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_camera_id
    FOREIGN KEY (camera_id)
        REFERENCES cameras (camera_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_user_id
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES users (user_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Like you, I was also stuck with this problem for a couple of hours :)